# Hamcrest Pattern Assert 2 Properties of Custom Collection

Tags: java, junit4, hamcrest, assertthat

I have a Java Custom Object collection `List<Employee>` with two (2) properties. It is received as a response of Web Service. The object seems like

```
public class Employee{
   public String getName(){ ... }
   public String getDesignation(){ ... }
}
```

I need to write an assertion to check if the name of the employee is **David** then its designation must be **Manager**. I tried it like that

`assertThat(employeeList, allOf(hasItem(hasProperty("name", equalTo("David")))
                , hasItem(hasProperty("designation", equalTo("Manager")))));`

but it passed if there is at least one Manager instance and one David. My requirement is to apply these two checks on a single instance.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a class `Foo`:

```
public class Foo {
    private String name;
    private String designation;

    public Foo(String name, String designation) {
        this.name = name;
        this.designation = designation;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }
}
```

And a custom Hamcrest matcher:

```
private static class FooMatcher extends BaseMatcher<List<Foo>> {
    public String name;
    public String designation;

    public static FooMatcher matches(String name, String designation) {
        return new FooMatcher(name, designation);
    }

    private FooMatcher(String name, String designation) {
        this.name = name;
        this.designation = designation;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object item) {
        Foo foo = (Foo) item;
        return foo.getName().equals(name) && foo.getDesignation().equals(designation);
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        // this is a quick impl, you'll probably want to fill this in!
    }
}
```

This test will pass:

```
@Test
public void canAssertOnMultipleFooAttributes() {
    List<Foo> incoming = Lists.newArrayList(new Foo("bill", "sir"), new Foo("bob", "mr"), new Foo("joe", "mr"));
    assertThat(incoming, hasItem(FooMatcher.matches("bob", "mr")));
}
```